# Ninject cyclical dependency issue with a binding that has no dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting a cyclical dependency error. I'm also getting many different activation paths and classes called out, seemingly at random.

This is a new issue in a system that has worked for over a year. It has been in active development so its ever changing and trying to roll back changes to figure out exactly where the issue popped up is a bit too cumbersome to do at this juncture.

It *seems* that this has to do with multithreading and race conditions. As I add more threads running, the error appears more frequently.

I had been struggling to figure this out, when one of the activation paths / dependencies called out by Ninject caught my attention. **One of my dependencies listed had NO dependencies itself.**

```
Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating IMetaValueProvider using binding from IMetaValueProvider to ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.

Activation path:
  6) Injection of dependency IMetaValueProvider into parameter valueProviders of constructor of type MetaValueResolverFactory
  5) Injection of dependency IMetaValueResolverFactory into parameter valueResolverFactory of constructor of type MessageExecutionContextFactory
  4) Injection of dependency IMessageExecutionContextFactory into parameter executionContextFactory of constructor of type MessageProcessor
  3) Injection of dependency IMessageProcessor into parameter messageProcessor of constructor of type MessageProcessingManager
  2) Injection of dependency IMessageProcessingManager into parameter messageProcessingManager of constructor of type QueuePollerFactory
  1) Request for QueuePollerFactory
```

In the above example, `ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider` has absolutely NO dependencies.

Below is the source to `ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DealerVision.Messaging
{
    public class ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider : IMetaValueProvider
    {
        public string MetaKeyPrefix
        {
            get
            {
                return "Output";
            }
        }

        public object GetMetaValue(IMessageExecutionContext context, string key)
        {
            if(context.ExecutableMessage.Result == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"{nameof(ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider)} cannot get key \"{key}\" because the {nameof(ExecutableMessageBase)} does not have a result.");
            }

            if (context.ExecutableMessage.Result.ExecutionOutput.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return context.ExecutableMessage.Result.ExecutionOutput[key];
            }

            return null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetPersistantKeys(IMessageExecutionContext executionContext)
        {
            if (executionContext.ExecutableMessage.Result == null)
                return Enumerable.Empty<string>();

            List<string> keys = new List<string>();

            foreach (var kvp in executionContext.ExecutableMessage.Result.ExecutionOutput)
            {
                keys.Add($"{this.MetaKeyPrefix}.{kvp.Key}");
            }

            return keys;
        }
    }
}
```

**Two questions:**

1. How can I tell exactly what the cyclical 2 dependencies are? Ninject does not list out BOTH dependencies involved in the cycle only one of them.
2. How could the one dependency being called out be considered part of the cycle if that dependency has NO dependencies itself. How would it be possible to have a cycle?

I'm apparently missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post a minimal verifiable example showing the problem.

Comment: Is this using asp.net, asp.net MVC? WCF?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit, No, it is a console app.

Comment: @Steven, wish I could. As you can tell in the activation path, it's not a simple 2 class thing. Furthermore, part of my issue as I mentioned was even finding the *both* classes causing the cyclical issue. Without posting my entire project, I do not know how to reasonably give a repeatable example.  That being said, I think I still asked some questions that could be answered without a code example

Comment: @RyanGriffith Like Steven said, minimal verifiable example would help. Might I also suggest to check for `OnActivation`, [DependencyCreation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.dependencycreation) and Interception creating new instances?

Comment: @RyanGriffith it may be a lot of work but is key. I suggest to start a project from scratch and copy only the relevant stuff. You can "mock" some of the types to make it easier. If the issue can't be reproduced, you need to "unmock" some types / behavior..

Answer (score 1):

Instances need to be created "bottom up" or "dependency first". That means, `ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider` is created before `MessageExecutionContextFactory` and that again is created before... `QueuePollerFactory`.

Now, ninject does stop at `ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider` because that would cause creation of a type further up in the chain. At this point it is not exactly stated which that would be.

Since you say `ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider` does not have any dependencies:
.

- check whether you are wrong:

  - Is there more than one constructor? Because if there's a constructor with a parameter that ninject has a binding for, it will use this one, not the one without parameters
  - is there property or method injection? Also see [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns)
  - is there a second type with the same name - and the binding is actually for the other type, not the one you expect? (also check for `Rebind` and conditional bindings).
- check for usage of `OnActivation` - this can lead to activations coupled to the instanciation of types
- usage of [DependencyCreation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.dependencycreation) extension can also lead to unobvious activations

Comment: I've included the source to `ExecutionOutputMetaValueProvider`. You can see, there are no dependencies. How is it possible that this binding is causing a cyclical dependency issue?

Comment: @RyanGriffith like i said in the post, `OnActivation` or `DependencyCreation` could mask such "dependencies" - as they are not being injected.